# How to restore data from MySQL .frm?

Tags: mysql

I have all data in MySQL's .frm files. How can I restore the data? I do not want to restore all of them, just some records and tables so I need to make dumps out of them.

From what I can see, there are only .frm files, no .myd files. There is, however, ibdata1 file. How am I supposed to restore?

Comment: Do you have a complete copy of mySQL's data directory?

Comment: You can't restore data from frm from files, because they only contain the schema. If you have ibdata files or one big ibdata file, then you have an innodb set of tables. [Link1](http://www.nerdydork.com/restoring-mysql-innodb-files-on-windows.html) [Link2](http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=28)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working.

1) I created an empty database named after what the real database was on the server in my local installation.

2) I killed "mysqld"

3) I copied the three ib* files to my local MySQL data directory (on Windows it was a hidden folder in root drive). Make sure you copied to InnoDB data file directory, depending on your my.cnf InnoDB and MyISAM data may be stored in different folders. I also copied the .frm files.

4) I ran `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" --innodb-force-recovery=6`

5) I ran `mysql -uroot -pmypass` to confirm `use mydb; select * from mytable;` returned results.

6) I used `mysqldump mydb mytable --compact > file.sql`

That's it!

Comment: You! mister..saved my life!

Comment: You led me to the solution - the `ibdata*` file was located within the `mysql/data/` file wherewas I was expecting them to be located within each respective database folder themselves.

Comment: I was constantly getting this error :: 

InnoDB:Ignoring the redo log due to missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT..
InnoDB:Plugin initialization aborted
Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error. registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

Then as per your guidance, I ran "mysqld --innodb-force-recovery=6" and also the APache. As a result, I was able to open PHPMyAdmin in browser and all tables opened in ReadOnly Mode. The best thing was I was able to export all the database in SQL format. It saved my life. I installed another Xampp and imported that SQL.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple Steps.

1. In Xampp Control Panel Click on config of MySql then select "my.ini" file.
2. In this file add a line `innodb_file_per_table=1` after `[mysqld]` line.
3. Now, I created a same database which you want to recovery like name as `exam_table`
4. Create one by one table which you want to restore like name as `exam_time`.
5. Run SQL query/queries `` ALTER TABLE `exam_time` DISCARD TABLESPACE; ``

   **Caution: This deletes the current .ibd file.**
6. Copy the backup `exam_time.frm` & `exam_time.ibd` file to the appropriate database directory.
7. Run SQL query/queries `ALTER TABLE tbl_name IMPORT TABLESPACE;`

Check Your `exam_time` table its recovered .....Hurrahhh