# Moving Xamp after formatting my computer and finding all my Databases empty

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, xampp

I recently had to format my computer but I made sure I backed-up all my files before. I am developing lots of local sites using Xamp on my Windows 7 machine.

When I tried to move the files back onto the same drive (c:) and then looked at PHPMYADMIN the tables where there but all empty.

I have all the xamp files including the .frm files but the phpmyadmin shows the DB's but they are all empty i.e showing no tables inside.

Really hope someone can help as I have potentially lost a LOT of work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which is your current operating System

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353412/how-to-restore-my-myi-myd-tables-from-frm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783761/how-to-restore-data-from-mysql-frm

Comment: Did you take backup sql from the phpmyadmin before formatting?

Answer (score 0):

When you said "I made sure I backed up all my files" -- which files are you talking about? There are the MySQL data files, the XAMPP program files, and then any exported .sql files you may have backed up. The best way to create a backup is to "dump" an SQL file from the database ("Export" from within phpMyAdmin, though I generally use the mysqldump command-line tool). If you didn't do that but still have the MySQL data directory, the links provided by Peter Michael will guide you (although relying on the MySQL data directory isn't generally a good backup means, because of various inconsistencies or loss that can occur with your data; whether it works at all also depends on your table type). I don't know where those data files are stored when using XAMPP and a cursory Google search gives a couple of different options, so good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. Unfortunately I didn't do a MySQL dump and do not have any SQL files. Does anyone know what I should do next? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you can find the database files on the file system, you can try copying them (the .MYD, .MYI, and .frm files); otherwise it sounds like you don't have the databases backed up.